# The method paint(Graphics g) of JComponent does not see the field

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, paint, jcomponent

I have an array of objects as the field of one of my classes
`public UserSquare[] userSquares = new UserSquare[8];`
When i handle whith this array in any regular method like

```
public void showSquares() {
    for(UserSquare square : userSquares) {
        System.out.println(square.x);
    }
}
```

then it outputs what i need)

```
0,413,87,87
87,413,87,87
174,413,87,87
261,413,87,87
348,413,87,87
435,413,87,87
522,413,87,87
609,413,87,87
```

But when i do the same in the method paint(Graphics g)

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    for(UserSquare sq : userSquares) {
        System.out.println(sq.x+","+sq.y+","+sq.width+","+sq.height);
    }
}
```

It does not see the array userSquares and throws the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: This means that the method runs before the array has been initialized.

Comment: Please share the complete code.

Comment: Instead of looping in the  `paint(Graphics g)` method yourself you could also try to call `showSquares()`: `public void paint(Graphics g) { showSquares(); }`

Comment: Don't override paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)`. And don't forget the `super.paintComponent(...)` at the start of the method.l